# Mongo query - finding minimum value within a document

Tags: mongodb

I want to find minimum value in a mongoDB document:

Sample document

```
db.marks.insert({"name" : "John", "subject1" : 100, "subject2" : 98, "subject3" : 99, "subject4" : 97});
```

I want to find minimum value of `subject1,subject2,subject3,subject4` inside each document. Tried to use aggregation framework for this, but it seems to work across documents. Is there a way to find value inside a document?

Comment: Can you change your data model? Something like {name: 'John', subjects : [ {name:"subject1", mark: 100}, {name:"subject2", mark: 98} ]} would make it a lot easier.

Comment: I can do that. But can i get minimum mark along with other fields?

Comment: I suggested that model to be easier to find the lowest grade across all subjects. If you want to add additional info for each subdocument go ahead.

Comment: can i do a mongo query to get lowest value from the data model you suggested?

Comment: Yes, it would be trivial doing it with the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate as below:

- `$group` by the name to transform the subject fields to array.
- `$project` a field named `score` as a `$setUnion` of all the scores per person.
- `$unwind` the `score` array.
- `$group` by the name again to find the `$min` score per person.

Code:

```
db.marks.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$name",
         "subject1":{$push:"$subject1"},
         "subject2":{$push:"$subject2"},
         "subject3":{$push:"$subject3"},
         "subject4":{$push:"$subject4"}}},
{$project:{"score":{$setUnion:["$subject1",
                               "$subject2",
                               "$subject3",
                               "$subject4"]}}},
{$unwind:"$score"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id","minScore":{$min:"$score"}}}
])
```